# Lost my ice cream truck ringtone

Tags: ringtone

I have a rzr hd and one of the stock ringtones was an ice cream truck. About a month ago, it disappeared from my phone. Any ideas? I don't know the name of it, but I haven't added any ringtones to my phone or connected it to a USB. The ringtone is just gone from the menu.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found an Ice Cream Truck ringtone in [Mobiles24](http://www.mobiles24.com/downloads/s/542416-m156-ice_cream_truck). Could you check if that's correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try re-applying `Factory settings` to your phone.

How to do it:

```
Your Home Screen->Menu->Settings->Privacy->Factory data reset.
```

**Caution:**

> Selecting this option erases all data into the phone. Please ensure
>   that You have proper backup in case some Unexpected issues surface!